# Регулярное выражение для поиска различных скобок

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, java-8

Имеется такая строка:

```
String someString = "{{[cc(c)ggg]}ssss}";
```

Необходимо отфильтровать её с помощью Regex или средствами Java 8 таким образом, что бы в ней остались лишь символы "{, }, [, ], (, )". Порядок следования элементов должен остатся прежним.

P.S. if-else не предлагать :)

Comment: `String result = someString.replaceAll("[^(){}\\]\\[]+", "");`. А что за проблема у вас?

Comment: Спасибо, подходит! Добавьте как ответ.

А проблема была в том, что я не верно, как оказалось, работал с квадратными скобками.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы добавить квадратные скобки в символьный класс, необходимо их экранировать. Такая необходимость продиктована тем, что символьные классы в регулярных выражениях Java поддерживают *объединение* (`[a-d[m-p]]` находит буквы от `a` до `d`, или от `m` до `p`), *пересечение* (`[a-z&&[def]]` находит только `d`, `e` или `f`) и *вычитание* (`[a-z&&[^bc]]` находит буквы от `a` до `z`, кроме `b` и `c`) именно с помощью квадратных скобок.

Используйте

```
String result = someString.replaceAll("[^(){}\\]\\[]+", "");
                                             ^^^^^^
```

См. [демо на Java](https://ideone.com/hh6dbb) и [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/psXQwV/1).

**Подробности**

- `[^` - начало отрицающего (негативного) символьного класса, который находит любой символ кроме

  - `(` - открывающей круглой скобки
  - `)` - закрывающей круглой скобки
  - `{` - открывающей фигурной скобки
  - `}` - закрывающей фигурной скобки
  - `\]` - закрывающей квадратной скобки
  - `\[` - открывающей квадратной скобки
- `]+` - 1 и более раз.